# Reading a set of sequences available in a text file in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have a .txt file named one.txt. It contains three sequences as follows.

> 1 -1 -1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
>   1 -1 1 -1 1 1

I am using a nested for loop to read the sequences available in the above file for three iterations as follows

```
int dd6[6];

ifstream f6;


for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

    f6.open("C:\\one.TXT");

        for(int i7=0;i7<3;i7++){

              for(int i8=0;i8<6;i8++){
                  f6>>dd6[i8];
                  cout<<dd6[i8]<<" ";
              } 
              cout<<"\n";   
        }
        f6.close();
        cout<<"\n";

}
```

As, shown in the above program, I need the 3 sequences available in one.txt to be read for three times as follows,

> 1 -1 -1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
>   1 -1 1 -1 1 1

........................

> 1 -1 -1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
>   1 -1 1 -1 1 1

.........................

> 1 -1 -1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
>   1 -1 1 -1 1 1

But, when I use the above program, I always get the output as follows where in the second and third triplets appear to be only the last sequence (1 1 -1 -1 1 1) three times.

> 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1
>   1 -1 1 -1 1 1
>   1 1 -1 -1 1 1

....................

> 1 1 -1 -1 1 1
>   1 1 -1 -1 1 1
>   1 1 -1 -1 1 1

.....................

> 1 1 -1 -1 1 1
>   1 1 -1 -1 1 1
>   1 1 -1 -1 1 1

What could have been the problem available in my code?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why read the same thing three times? Why not just read it once and output it three times?

Comment: You've not accepted _any_ answers of 4 questions you've posted.

Comment: @ R.Martinho Fernandes:: This is not my actual code. I am actually reading 34 length sequences from a text file which contains 2384729237 sequences. I have three other text files which have the same number of sequences. I have to consider all the possibilities available between all the sequences to generate a matrix. Therefore I have to 2384729237*2384729237*2384729237*2384729237 total number of possibilities.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate this. Using the exact same code, mine prints out fine. Is this the exact code you're using? And have you tried compiling the code you posted?

Comment: @Chamikara you'll have a hard time getting people to solve an issue that exists in your code by showing code that doesn't have that issue.

Comment: 'This is not my actual code', 'text file' that we do not have.  Why would you think that we can debug this in any more efficient way than you can?

Comment: Look at my answer, the problem arise because the error flag is set in the ifstream object due to the fact you reached the EOF. Just clear the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the problem, but instead of closing and opening the file you could just send the get pointer to the beginning of the file with

```
f6.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

**EDIT: ANSWERED**

Here is the correct code. When the stream reaches the end of file, it set an error flag and from then on the readings are wrong. You have to clear the stream before reading it again.
I wrote a version of the program without re-opening the stream every time, but it works even if you open and close the file.

```
int dd6[6];

ifstream f6;
f6.open("C:\\one.TXT");

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

    //f6.open("C:\\one.TXT");

        for(int i7=0;i7<3;i7++){
              for(int i8=0;i8<6;i8++){

                  f6>>dd6[i8];
                  cout<<dd6[i8]<<" ";
              } 
              cout<<"\n";   
        }
        f6.clear(); //clear the error flags!
        f6.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        cout<<"\n";

}
```